# Getting "Unknown resource" error when endpoint is lower than six characters

Tags: graphql, react-admin

I'm setting up a react-admin app with graphql-simple dataProvider. When I declare a query type over six characters, the dataProvider does not recognise the resource I defined.

Client configuration (dependencies)

```
"graphql": "^14.1.1",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"ra-data-graphql-simple": "^2.6.0",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-admin": "^2.6.4",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-scripts": "2.1.3"
```

Server configuration (dependencies)

```
"apollo-server": "^2.3.3",
"graphql": "^14.1.1"
```

Resolvers :

```
    Dog(parent, args, context, info) {
      return dogs[0];
    },
    allDogs() {
      return dogs;
    },
    _allDogsMeta() {
      return 2;
    },

    Salesperson(parent, args, context, info) {
      return Salespersons[0];
    },
    allSalespersons() {
      return Salespersons;
    },
    _allSalespersonsMeta() {
      return 2;
    }
```

GraphQL Definition

```
type Query {
    Dog(id: ID!): Dog
    allDogs: [Dog]
    _allDogsMeta(
      page: Int
      perPage: Int
      sortField: String
      sortOrder: String
      filter: ClientFilter
    ): ListMetadata

    Salesperson(id: ID!): Salesperson
    allSalespersons: [Salesperson]
    _allSalespersonsMeta(
      page: Int
      perPage: Int
      sortField: String
      sortOrder: String
      filter: ClientFilter
    ): ListMetadata
}

type Dog {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}
type Salesperson {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
}
```

The "Dog" resource appears on my app but the "Salesperson" is not detected by ra-data-graphql-simple.